# FadeTo animation doesn't work. cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, fade, ccnode

According to this code node must slowly appear, right? It doesn't work. What is wrong?

```
   CCNodeColor *_backNode = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0    alpha:1.0f]];
    _backNode.opacity=0;
    [self addChild:_backNode z:5];
  [_backNode runAction:[CCActionFadeTo actionWithDuration:2 opacity:0.9]];
```

Comment: Isn't fully opaque 255?

Comment: @PWiggin What do you mean exactly? Opacity value can be from 0 to 1. Alfa is already set 0, because node must appear(not disappear)

Comment: Granted, I'm using an older version of cocos2d than you are, but I always go from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with alpha = 0 and not setting opacity:

```
CCNodeColor *_backNode = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 
                                                                    green:0
                                                                     blue:0
                                                                    alpha:0.0f]];
```

Comment: just the same :( can it be a bug?

Comment: Possibly. Maybe try with another node, a sprite for instance. That really ought to work.